# how to hide an element data-bind who doesn't have an id or class

Tags: css

in my case i want to hide this element below from a form (this field is getting generated automatically) who doesn't have a specific id , so if i want to hide it it's easy 'display: none' but I can't find a specific class or id to put the style on it

Can anyone tell how to hide this attribute please ?

```
<div class="admin__field" data-bind="css: $data.additionalClasses, attr: {'data-index': index}, visible: visible" data-index="zd_user_id">
    <!-- ko if: $data.label --><div class="admin__field-label" data-bind="visible: $data.labelVisible">
        <label data-bind="attr: {for: uid}" for="L2LLLF9">
            <span data-bind="attr: {'data-config-scope': $data.scopeLabel}, i18n: label">Zendesk User Id</span>
        </label>
    </div><!-- /ko -->
    <div class="admin__field-control" data-bind="css: {'_with-tooltip': $data.tooltip, '_with-reset': $data.showFallbackReset &amp;&amp; $data.isDifferedFromDefault}">
        <!-- ko ifnot: hasAddons() --><!-- ko template: elementTmpl -->
<input class="admin__control-text" type="text" data-bind="
        event: {change: userChanges},
        value: value,
        hasFocus: focused,
        valueUpdate: valueUpdate,
        attr: {
            name: inputName,
            placeholder: placeholder,
            'aria-describedby': noticeId,
            id: uid,
            disabled: disabled,
            maxlength: 255
    }" name="customer[zd_user_id]" aria-describedby="notice-L2LLLF9" id="L2LLLF9" maxlength="255">
<!-- /ko --><!-- /ko -->

        <!-- ko if: hasAddons() --><!-- /ko -->

        <!-- ko if: $data.tooltip --><!-- /ko -->

        <!-- ko if: $data.showFallbackReset && $data.isDifferedFromDefault --><!-- /ko -->

        <!-- ko if: error --><!-- /ko -->

        <!-- ko if: $data.notice --><!-- /ko -->

        <!-- ko if: $data.additionalInfo --><!-- /ko -->

        <!-- ko if: $data.hasService() --><!-- /ko -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i can see class admin__field and admin__control-text

Comment: All the attributes of this form has the same so i can't hide all of teem

Comment: there has to be something unique in the form, either above or below in the hierarchy that you can start from with the selection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following code:

```
.class_name:nth-child(number) { display: none }
```

And set 'number' to the integer count of the element you wish to hide.

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you try something like

```
[data-bind]:not([class*="admin"]) {
   display: none;
}
```

This will hide all data-bind elements that have class which contains `admin`.

You may extend this for IDs as well, but in general it is not perfect and robus solution.

**You should try to change your HTML and select elements in correct way instead of such hacks**

Answer (score 0):

Give it a style with `display` set to `none`:

```css
<div style='display: none'></div>
```